# Django with request in ajax

Tags: ajax, django, post, view

This is my request in ajax,

```
var req=$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/create/travel',  // or just url: "/my-url/path/"
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
                startPlace:nameStart,
                startLng:lngStart,
                startLat:latStart,
                endPlace:nameEnd,
                ...
            }
        });
```

Then, it is my view

```
def createT(request):
  if request.is_ajax():
    #print(request.POST['board'])
    print(Car.objects.get(number_plate=request.POST['number_plate']))
    travel1=Travel.objects.create(
      name=request.POST['name_travel'],
      startPlace=request.POST['startPlace'],
      ...
      )

    return render_to_response('travel/meTravel.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But django not go to the template, i dont know how i go to other view or open other page, other template,

Simply when i come to this view,  i cannot open other view, single django stay in the same page. =$

Help me! Tanks ,

Comment: You've only shown half of the Ajax JS. Where's the rest? What is your success function? What are you hoping to happen?

Comment: I do not know to put on the success function.. to render other view...

Comment: So are you saying you want to actually go to another page? If so, why are you using Ajax in the first place? Just do a normal form POST.

Comment: I dont undertand very good your answer but yes, i need go to other page, but first, i need go to the view to make one object and save in the database, after i dont know what could navigate to other page.....

Comment: Is correct if a do this?   req.done(function(data) {
window.location="http://localhost:8000/TravelsMe";
  });

Comment: as daniel said why don't you use only POST ?

Answer (score 0):

finally, I make a form and send the normal request, Tanks for all...

```
class TravelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Travel
        exclude=("responsible",)
        widgets = {
        'date': DateTimeWidget (attrs={'id':"date"},use_tz=True,bootstrap_version=3)
        }

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TravelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['number_plate'].queryset = Car.objects.filter(proprietor=user)
```

and my view

```
def TravelCreate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TravelForm(request.user.id, request.POST)
        print("POST HERE-----------------=)")
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
          obj=form.save(commit=False)
          obj.responsible = request.user
          obj.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/TravelsMe') 
    else:
          form = TravelForm(request.user.id)

    return render_to_response('travel/travel_form.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And some code of ajax,